# Absolute URL to relative URL for Global Nav

Tags: navigation

Someone hard-coded the links in the Global Navigation section. Now that we are changing inside.old.com to inside.new.com I need to figure out a way to change 4 links under the Global Navigation so that http://inside.old.com/HR/Pages/default.aspx is not /HR/Pages/default.aspx.

I can't do this manually for QAQC or DEV or Prod farm since there are 300 different places per farm. Is there a powershell way to tackle this. Please suggest. I am kind of under super time crunch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this may help.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fb90034c-76f5-4cc5-9e73-7e4783f8c779/powershell-script-to-add-hierarchy-in-global-navigation

Comment: Please provide some details from the link to make your answer less dependent on it. What will happen if the link goes broken? :)